# Make PayPal business account split incoming payments to other accounts

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I'm working on a software project in a group of developers and we plan to sell the product via an electronic payment system such as PayPal. In this connection, we wonder if it would be possible to set up a business account with PayPal (or any other payment system) in a way that makes any received payment split according to a certain ratio and the shares automatically transferred to other accounts?

If it's possible with PayPal, how we do it or where do we find any help docs on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to split payments, you can use PayPal's Express Checkout or Adaptive Payments to split up the funds into different accounts.  Using Express Checkout with parallel payments, you can split up the transaction up and the receivers of the payment will pay the fees according to the amount they received.  The buyer will see the different receivers that were involved in the transaction.  If you use Adaptive Payments you can set who pays the fees, and it can be set up so the buyer does not see the other parties involved.